# ASP.NET Web API and MongoDB Atlas - Method to Retrieve Specific Data from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, get, mongodb-.net-driver

I have created an ASP.NET Web API project (using .NET Framework 4.6.1) in Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 that utilizes MongoDb Atlas via the MongoDB .NET Driver. The project stores "Patients" with a few different attributes.

I have successfully implemented a Get() method to return a "Patient". I now want to implement a GetMedications() method to return only the medications of a particular "Patient". Below are the pertinent methods in my "PatientsController" file:

```
public async Task<Patient> Get(string id)
{
    try
    {
        ObjectId internalId = GetInternalId(id);
        return await _patients.Find(p => p.Id == id || p.InternalId == internalId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

[Route("api/patients/{id}/medications")]
public async Task<Medication> GetMedications(string id)
{
    try
    {
        ObjectId internalId = GetInternalId(id);
        var patient = await _patients.Find(p => p.Id == id || p.InternalId == internalId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        return patient.Medications;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private ObjectId GetInternalId(string id)
{
    ObjectId internalId;
    if (!ObjectId.TryParse(id, out internalId))
        internalId = ObjectId.Empty;

    return internalId;
}
```

Visual studio displays this error for `return patient.Medications`:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WebAPIDemo.Models.Medication>' to 'WebAPIDemo.Models.Medication'
```

Here is my Patient class (and other applicable classes):

```
public class Patient
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId InternalId { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ailment> Ailments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Medication> Medications { get; set; }
}

public class Medication
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Doses { get; set; }
}

public class Ailment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How could I properly write the GetMedications() method?

Comment: What you want to return means medications or only one medication?

Comment: If you want to return one medication then return only one medication not its collection.or you want to return collection then change the method return type to collection or list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are returning a collection when your method only returns one item, so you need to make sure the types match.

Change the return type of your method:

```
public async Task<ICollection<Medication>> GetMedications(string id)
```

Comment: Such a simple fix! Thanks, Guys!